# Using Spring @Value systemProperties into Managed Bean

Tags: spring, jsf

I want inject systemProperties into a JSF Managed Bean (jsf 1.2 ).

The only way that this can be done  is if I either use a managed property or create a systemProperties bean and inject that into the managed bean I want, correct? I can't use @Value like; It has to be a spring bean in order for me to do that.

`#{systemProperties['databaseName']}`

`#{systemProperties.databaseName}`

Managed Property

```
    <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>fooUI</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>test.foo</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>systemPropertyExample</property-name>
        <value>#{systemProperties['systemPropertyExample']}</value>
    </managed-property>  
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF managed beans *can* be spring managed. You just have to configure a spring-specific `<el-resolver>` in faces-config.xml:

```
<el-resolver>
     org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

It will resolve managed beans within the spring context (of course, you need a `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml that bootstraps spring, but I assume you have that). Then you can use `@Value`, dependency injection, etc, in your jsf beans.

The only difference is that you will be defining them with `@Controller @Scope("request")` rather than with xml.

Comment: That's what I thought, and I DO HAVE THE EL-RESOLVER defined, and load my spring xml through the ContextLoaderListener. Do I have to use the @Controller annotation in conjunction with the @Value? Right now I just have my managed beans defined in the faces-config xml.

Comment: sorry about the caps, the edit thing on this wouldn't let me make a change to lower that lol

Comment: @Controller is not a managed bean. It is Spring bean. Question is about JSF bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the JSF Bean with `@Configurable`, then you can use it like a spring bean. (Attention this requires the use of AspectJ)

Comment: When you say requires the use of AspectJ, do you mean just the jar for Spring AspectJ has to be on the classpath or some configuratino for it as well?

Comment: I mean AspectJ compile time weaving -- But I guess Bozho's answer I a better solution